# Downloading Sqlite backup file from google drive ends up with a corrupt file nodejs + Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, google-drive-api

I am working on a backup system with Google Drive v3 REST API. I upload a sqlite backup file to a folder on Google Drive. That works. I am able to upload and list the files in the folder.

So now I am working on restoring that file in my application. But when I download the file and write the response stream I end up with a corrupted db file. When I open it up in notepad ++ I see that any special characters such as ^ etc are all squares and the file is like 2 mb bigger than what was uploaded.

I have been at this for two days now and cannot figure out why the file is not writing 1:1 copy of what is downloaded

this is my current code for the download ..

```
async restoreGoogleDriveDatabase(fileId){
        const url = encodeURI(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media`);
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
            },
        }
       await fetch(url, options).then(async response => response.text())
           .then(arrayBuffer => {

const path = require('path').join(window.process.env.ProgramData, 'Home Inventory');
               fs.writeFile(`${path}\\HomeInventory1.db`, arrayBuffer, function () {
                   console.warn('file created');
               });
           });
    },
```

Looking for any kind of help that would get me back on the right track.

Comment: firstly, use async/await OR `.then` - no reason to use both ... secondly, have you tried `response => response.arrayBuffer()` ... thirdly, what has this to do with `vue` since this is clearly nodejs code on the server?

Comment: Good point with the async/await. I have tried using `response.arrayBuffer()` with the same results. It uploads in the correct ISO format but does not download in that same format and I'm not understanding why.  Vue is just my front end interface which I execute the nodejs commands through the Vuex actions. The tag was not meant for an issue within Vue just a reference to the framework that I am using

Comment: the other confusing thing is `window.process.env.ProgramData` ... `window` in nodejs? anyway, are you 100% sure the upload isn't corrupting the file?

Comment: Yes im sure I have opened the backup file on google drive copied pasted it into a new Notepad++ doc saved it with db extension and opened it in sql browser no issues . but when i download and write it . the special characters come out as squares  no idea why

Comment: possibly a character encoding issue?

Comment: Yeah I think so too but no Idea how to change it. I read that sqlite is utf-8 encoding so I tried that and still same squares. if you have any other ideas please feel free to let me know and ill try it.

Comment: About `It uploads in the correct ISO format but does not download in that same format`, for example, when you manually download the file instead of Drive API, will you download the correct data?

Comment: Maybe `arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();` and `fs.writeFile(\`${path}\\HomeInventory1.db\`, Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, "binary"), ....` - all up, like this https://pastebin.com/C66duAuy ... note, using `fs/promises` since using async/await it makes more sense to do so

Comment: yes when I go into Google Drive right click the file and select download it downloads correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX - That worked. I am able to open the downloaded db file.

Comment: @DRW - added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with character encoding

The simplest fix is to fetch the result as an arrayBuffer, and write out the arrayBuffer using "binary" encoding

Like so

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');

async restoreGoogleDriveDatabase(fileId) {
    const url = encodeURI(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media`);
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
        },
    }
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
        const path = require('path').join(window.process.env.ProgramData, 'Home Inventory');
        await fs.writeFile(`${path}/HomeInventory1.db`, Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, "binary"));
        console.warn('file created');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
},
```

The code above uses async/await correctly, and also uses `fs/promises` instead of `fs`, since already using `async/await` it makes sense to use the Promise version of `fs` methods

The important changes are

```
response.arrayBuffer()
```

To get the response as an `arrayBuffer`

and in `fs.writeFile` use

```
Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, "binary")
```

To write the data "as-is" to the file